# What is the alternative for WinVerifyTrust Api in Driver?

Tags: c++, c, driver, digital-signature, filter-driver

From what I have seen [here](http://forum.sysinternals.com/how-to-use-winverifytrust-api-in-driver_topic20372.html) can not use `WinVerifyTrust` Api in Driver.

So my question How can I check digital signature in filter driver?